# Django project is not reading my static css file

Tags: django

I am working on a django project and for some reason the style.css file is not read. However, my static images are working. Not really sure what the issue is, any help is greatly appreciated. There are also no errors showing in the console and terminal..

Link to my github repository

https://github.com/Amanuel763/petwebsite

Comment: Change `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static',]` and try again

Comment: just tried to change it to 'static', but it gave me an error due to the static root according to the error

Answer (score 0):

Add `STATIC_URL` and  `STATIC_ROOT` to your `urls.py`. See more about [**Serving static files during development[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: same issue. no error, but the css file is still not read